# How to write a Aggregation Pipeline to get a merged document as new field on document insert MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm newbie on MongoDB and I'll show my question with a example. Scenario:

- 3 Collections;

**Collection_1**

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "idLocal": 1023,
    "idType": 21 
},
{
    "_id": 2,
    "idLocal": 1029,
    "idType": 21 
},
{
    "_id": 3,
    "idLocal": 923,
    "idType": 22 
}
```

**Collection_2**

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "idLOp": 1,
    "idType": 21    
},
{
    "_id": 2,
    "idOp": 5,
    "idType": 21 
}
{
    "_id": 3,
    "idOp": 1,
    "idType": 12 
}
```

So, to insert a new document on Collection_3 I want create a new doc appending the docs from Collection_1 and Collection_2 with the follow conditions:

```
idLocal (Collection_1) == idLocal (New doc to insert) // get desired doc from Collection_1
idOp (Collection_2) == idOp (New doc to insert) AND idType (Collection_1 ) == idType  (Collection_2) // get desired doc from Collection_2
```

**Sample doc to insert**

```
{
    "_id": 5,
    "idOp": 1,
    "idLocal": 1023
}
```

**Collection_3**

```
// new doc saved at Collection_3 result desired:

{
    "_id": 5,
    "idOP": 1,
    "idLocal": 1023,
    "Collection_1_doc": { 
          "_id": 1,
          "idLocal": 1023,
          "idType": 21  
    },
    "Collection_2_doc": {
           "_id": 1,
           "idLOp": 1,
           "idType": 21 
    }
}
```

So, how I can use the MongoDB pipeline tools to make it? I never writed a pipeline before and don't know use the functions.

Comment: You can try with the [`$lookup stage`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup)

Comment: I don't know use the pipeline

Comment: So you want to insert the doc or return the doc as a projection?

Comment: The new doc must be saved at Collection_3.

Comment: I am afraid you can't do it in a single go, you need two operations, first fetching the linked data and then inserting it

Answer (score 0):

You can't write an aggregate pipeline that upserts in a single-go because MongoDb 4.2 [`supports`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) only these stages in pipeline -

- $addFields
- $set
- $project
- $unset
- $replaceRoot
- $replaceWith

and because you want to link the documents from collection 1 and collection 2, you can't use update with an aggregation pipeline.

---

So one way is as follows -

The first step would be to fetch the linked data, for that start by doing an aggregate on `collection_1` and [`lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) the linked docs in `collection_2` and fetch the first found doc using [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator,

```
var doc3 = {
    "_id": 5,
    "idOp": 1,
    "idLocal": 1023
};

db.Collection_1.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            idLocal: doc3.idLocal
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
           from: 'Collection_2',
           pipeline: [
              { 
                $match: { 
                    $expr: { 
                        $eq: [ "$idOp",  doc.idOp ] 
                    }
                }
              }
           ],
           as: "Collection_2_data"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            Collection_1: {
                _id: '$_id',
                idLocal: '$idLocal',
                idType: '$idType'
            },
            Collection_2: {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                    '$Collection_2_data',
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

[`MongoPlayground link`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pp-3GjmHrxz), Which gives -

```
[
  {
    "Collection_1": {
      "_id": 1,
      "idLocal": 1023,
      "idType": 21
    },
    "Collection_2": {
      "_id": 3,
      "idOp": 1,
      "idType": 12
    }
  }
]
```

Since the result of an aggregate query is always wrapped in an array, access the first index safely and append it to your `doc3` and insert it.

Assuming you're using mongoose, this is the code of the above idea -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

(async () => {
    try {
        let doc3 = {
            _id: 5,
            idOp: 1,
            idLocal: 1023
        };

        const pipeline = [
            {
                $match: {
                    idLocal: doc3.idLocal
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                   from: 'Collection_2',
                   pipeline: [
                      { 
                        $match: { 
                            $expr: { 
                                $eq: [ "$idOp",  doc.idOp ] 
                            }
                        }
                      }
                   ],
                   as: "Collection_2_data"
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 0,
                    Collection_1: {
                        _id: '$_id',
                        idLocal: '$idLocal',
                        idType: '$idType'
                    },
                    Collection_2: {
                        $arrayElemAt: [
                            '$Collection_2_data',
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ];

        const linkedDocsResult = await Collection_1.aggregate(pipeline).exec();
        
        if (linkedDocsResult.length) {
            doc3 = Object.assign(Object.create(null), doc3, linkedDocsResult[0]);
        }
        
        await Collection_3.create(doc3);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Nice answer. This is a little complex for me, otherwise, I can get only the ID of the document to insert o a new document instead copy the entire document?